# When smart switch is off, then power outlet/socket is not working

Tags: electrical, switch

Recently I replaced what is probably single pole switch that controlled ceiling light with a single pole smart dimmer switch. The original switch seemed to have two loads and one line, one white and one copper. So I hooked them all with the smart switch. The eiling light works perfectly now. But there is a power socket in the room that's not working when the light is off. It appears like the second load on the switch may be running to this socket? How can I have the smart switch do its business but keep  the socket live all the time?

Comment: So supply the socket from the line, check the diagram and the original connections that you made before taking it apart.

Answer (score 3):

### It actually had 2 lines and 1 load.

One of the line's was the "always-hot" power supply from the panel.  The other took "always-hot" power onward to other systems and outlets in the house.

You inadvertently moved the second one to the "load" side of the switch, so now it is interrupted by the switch.  Correct that.

Generally experimentation is very risky (because some combinations will seem to work and later kill you)... but when it involves black wires going to a switch, it's pretty safe.